# Create template for PDF creation in Cocoa / Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pdf

I am coding a Mac application. I want to give the user the opportunity to create a template for PDF creation. The PDF should be created from different NSTextFields where the users types in. So, the PDF creation should be dynamic. For example for an invoice. The format stays while the information on the PDF changes.

I use a NSTextView with a ruler which is always shown. Now I want to write for example `<TextField1>` in some point of the Sheet and where this TextField1 is, the input from TextField1 should be. I thought about getting the position of TextField1 and using it in the PDF creating process. But I am still not sure if its the right way. The PDF should always be for A4 format. Is it even possible to set the PDF View (on the screen) to an A4 view, so the user can see how the PDF will look in a printed version ?

The ruler is shown by using `[textView setRulerVisible:YES];`

Comment: Create a view in the background with all text fields laid out where you want them to be with the dimensions you need, fill in the fields when the user entered her/his input and export the view to PDF?

Comment: It´s possible. The main point is that I want to give the user the possibility to position the fields (in an easy way for example by dragging) by himself. Additionally I want to give him the possibility to create or delete some fields.